# How to specify an output filename with the Webpack CLI?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, command-line-interface

I want to create a **file** named `background.js` inside my `build` folder. This is the command I use:

```
webpack --mode production ./src/background -o ./build/background.js
```

But this creates a **folder** named `background.js` inside my build folder. I didn't find any other flag on the [webpack-cli documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/). So how do I specify an output filename with the Webpack CLI?

Answer (score 7):

You could try `--output-filename`:
https://v4.webpack.js.org/api/cli/#output-options

```
webpack --mode production --entry src/background/index.js --output-filename background.js -o ./build
```

Per the docs, here's a list of core flags from v4 that are supported in v5:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/tree/next/packages/webpack-cli#webpack-5

Comment: I use `"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"` but I get `Unknown argument: --output-filename error ` message when I use `--output-filename`

Answer (score 1):

in the **webpack.config.js** folder add this on the top,

```
const path = require("path");
```

then your **Module exports** will be:

```
module.exports = {
module: {
    rules: [ 
        // your rules, eg, babel loder.
    ],
},
    // the main solution
entry: "./src/index.js", // your entry file that you want it to be bundled for production
output: { // the output file path,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),// build is your folder name.
    filename: "background.js", // your specific filename to be built in the build folder.
}, };
```

and finally your **package.json** **build script** will be

```
"build": "webpack --mode production",
```